# C++ Macro creation of objects

Tags: c++, object, macros

I think my understanding of Macros is off. I am using curses to make a game and I want to generate a map (Uniformly picking tiles right now since I can't get any of the distribution samplers I find to work).

```
#include "Map.h"

/*  Our ingame tiles    */
#define WATER   Tile(COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_CYAN,std::string(1, static_cast<char>(247)));
#define LAVA    Tile(COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_RED, std::string(1, static_cast<char>(247)));
#define ANIMAL  Tile(COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_BLACK, std::string(1, static_cast<char>(224)));
#define PATH    Tile(COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_WHITE, std::string(1, static_cast<char>(32)));

//static int pathPx = 5;
//static int lavaPx = 2;
//static int waterPx = 2;
//static int animalPx = 1;

std::vector<Tile> tiles = {PATH, LAVA, WATER, ANIMAL};

std::vector< std::vector<Tile> > map;


Map::Map(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int y = rand() % 10 + 10; 
    int x = rand() % 10 + 10;
    for (int j=0; j<y; j++){
        std::vector<Tile> tileRowi;
        for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
            int n = rand()%4+1;
            tileRowi.push_back(tiles[n]);
        }
    }
}
```

Errors are:

```
   First: c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' [-fpermissive]
```

Second one: `invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`

The first one says line 485 of one of my files... but there is no line 485. 
The second one is on:

```
    std::vector<Tile> tiles = {PATH, LAVA, WATER, ANIMAL};
```

**edit--**

Here is my Tile class:

```
 #include "Tile.h"


int backgroundColor;
int foregroundColor;
std::string rep;

Tile::Tile(int fc, int bc, std::string r){
    backgroundColor = bc;
    foregroundColor = fc;
    rep = r;
}
```

**edit 2-- workspace pic**
[image: Here are the errors]

Comment: Are you sure you are including `<vector>` and whatever defines `Tile`?

Comment: Yes, I'm including everything in my map.h

Comment: In addition to a function, you can use an initializer list in C++11: `std::vector<Tile> tiles{WATER, LAVA, ANIMAL, PATH};`

Comment: Yes, That's what I just did. I had to add the flag in eclipse, I was wondering why it wouldn't work before, then I read somewhere else that I needed the flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ doesn't not allow operation outside function, put below code into a function

```
tiles.push_back(WATER);
tiles.push_back(LAVA);
tiles.push_back(ANIMAL);
tiles.push_back(PATH);
```

Map.cpp:

```
void MakeTiles(std::vector<Tile>& tiles)
{
  tiles.push_back(WATER);
  tiles.push_back(LAVA);
  tiles.push_back(ANIMAL);
  tiles.push_back(PATH);
}
```

**Edit**

As you haven't posted Tile class, I have to guess what's happening in your end.
Looks like you have a std::string type member in Tile which takes a char to construct it(refer to 3rd parameter of Tile)? A possible fix is:

```
  std::string(1, static_cast<char>(247));
```

Also your macros have extra `;` in the end

```
#define WATER   Tile(COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_CYAN,std::string(1, static_cast<char>(247)));
                                                                                  ^^^^
```

should be:

```
#define WATER   Tile(COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_CYAN,std::string(1, static_cast<char>(247)))
```

Comment: you forgot to include some headers? like: `#include <vector>`, or updated your question with new errors plz

Comment: Updated it. Sorry for delay.

Comment: Oh yeah, I did have std::string earlier. I changed it to char. But I changed it back again and followed your recommendation. I will update my question again to reflect these changes in a bit. I still have a few more errors on the same line but I think I can figure them out eventually. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Actually I just updated it again with a screenshot of my workspace. Do you think you could help me out one more time? I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: That's C++11, initialize list, VS may not support it atm. you still have to use push_back instead, but it will work in GCC latest version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21590/discussion-between-coolguy123-and-billz)

Answer (score 0):

i agree with above post.  push_back is the way to go.  but here's the macro way, loading up the vector with assignment operator.  cheers :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define WHITE tiles white(1,'w') //messy ihmo
#define BLACK tiles black(-1,'b')

using namespace std;

class tiles
{
public:
tiles(int NUMBER, char LETTER):number(NUMBER), letter(LETTER){};
int number;
char letter;
};

int main()
{
WHITE; //macro overwrites here
BLACK;

vector<tiles> box; //initialize the vector
box.reserve(8); //must do this manually if you don't use stl push_back()
                //or get memory error, bounds issue.  push_back() is really the better way 
                //to go.
int i=0;
box[i++]=white;//load up the vector via the assignment operator 
box[i]=black;//same

cout<<"WHITE "<<box[0].letter<<" BLACK "<<box[1].letter<<endl;//check to screen
cout<<"WHITE "<<box[0].number<<" BLACK "<<box[1].number<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```